# HKUnit for Sleep Analysis?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm need to query HealthKit for HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSleepAnalysis data, but can't find the compatible HKUnit for quantity value. Apple documentation is silent on units for Sleep Analysis. Am hoping someone already knows the answer.

BTW, the iOS Health app shows Hrs & Minutes on the Sleep chart, but the HKUnit reference doesn't include options for such composite units.

Comment: maybe [this tutorial on sleep analysis in HealthKit](http://benoitpasquier.fr/sleep-healthkit/) will help you

Comment: No. I read through that already and it has no indication of what units the query 'value' has.

Comment: For clarification, I'm using the HK query functions provided in AppCore  (https://github.com/ResearchKit/AppCore/blob/master/APCAppCore/APCAppCore/Library/Scoring/APCScoring.m). Those assume a unit parameter.  Looks like I'll have to bypass those for now.

Answer (score 3):

In [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis) I found this:

> By comparing the start and end times of these samples, apps can calculate a number of secondary statistics: the amount of time it took for the user to fall asleep, the percentage of time in bed that the user actually spent sleeping, the number of times the user woke while in bed, and the total amount of time spent both in bed and asleep.

This means that you have to use the startDate and endDate property of your sample to calculate sleep durations.

Answer (score 1):

Sleep samples are instances of `HKCategorySample`, which is unit-less.  You should perform calculations for sleep samples using the `startDate` and `endDate` properties on the sample.